# Problemas con múltiples casos

Tags: java, netbeans

tengo un problema sencillo y no soy muy experto en el tema, espero que me puedan ayudar.

Estoy creando un *JFrame*, al cual implemento los eventos del ratón *MouseMotionListener, MouseListener* y mi JFrame contiene 4 botones para cada figura(Circulo, cuadrado, triángulo, rectán.), cada uno tiene su *ActionPerformed* ,

Lo que necesito es que cuando utilice el *MouseReleased* se creen figuras dependiendo el botón presionado anteriormente, ya que solo puedo utilizar el método *Mouse Release* una vez.

¿Cómo puedo agregar todos los ActionPerformed en el método *Mouse Released* para los diferentes casos habiendo dado click en culaquier botón (Circulo, cuadrado, triángulo, rectán.)?

Answer (score 0):

Cuando ejecutas este código y haces clic en el botón, Java imprime:

Mouse Pressed
Action Performed
Released Mouse
Clicked mouse

Esto significa que Action Performed se ejecuta antes de que el mouse haga clic.

```js
import java.io.IOException ;
import java.awt.BorderLayout ;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent ;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener ;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent ;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener ;
import javax.swing.JButton ;
import javax.swing.JFrame ;

public class TestClass {
  public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Welcome") ;
    JButton b = new JButton("Hi") ;
    f.getContentPane().add(b, BorderLayout.CENTER) ;
    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      /**
       * actionPerformed
       *
       * @param e ActionEvent
       */
      public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Action Performed") ;
      }
    }
    ) ;
    b.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
      /**
       * mouseClicked
       *
       * @param e MouseEvent
       */
      public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Mouse Clicked") ;
      }

      /**
       * mouseEntered
       *
       * @param e MouseEvent
       */
      public void mouseEntered (MouseEvent e) {
      }

      /**
       * mouseExited
       *
       * @param e MouseEvent
       */
      public void mouseExited (MouseEvent e) {
      }

      /**
       * mousePressed
       *
       * @param e MouseEvent
       */
      public void mousePressed (MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Mouse Pressed") ;
      }

      /**
       * mouseReleased
       *
       * @param e MouseEvent
       */
      public void mouseReleased (MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Mouse Released") ;
      }

    }
    ) ;
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE) ;
    f.setSize(300, 300) ;
    f.setVisible(true) ;
  }
}
```

Comment: Gracias Amigo, no es exactamente pero si estamos cerca, supongamos que tengo 3 botones a=Circulo, b= Tringulo, c= Rectángulo, dentro de sus repectivos actionPerformed contiene lo que el código para poder hacer el dibujo, despues de oprimir por ejemplo el botón a=btnCirculo al hacer el MouseReleased debe identificar cuál presione para que dibuje un circulo en el panel y llame el método que esta dentro del actionPerformed Exclusivo del botón circulo ya que fue presionado.

Comment: Puedes usar la sentencia _Switch case_ dentro del actionPerformed

Comment: Gracias, aunque cada figura cuenta con su action performed, tengo el método de crear la figura, agregarlo a mi ArrayList y visualizarla en el panel, ¿dónde implementaría el Switch Case, dentro del mouseReleased o el ActionPerformed? Me ayudaria mucho ya que sólo falta este paso y desconozco de estas utilidades, me habían comentado que puedo usar por ejemplo el; `if(e.getSource().equals(btnCirculo)`

Comment: También podría llamar lo que está dentro del ActionPerformed y cuando sea usado el mouseReleased identificará el botón que presioné anteriormente y formar la figura?   Cómo podría llamar lo que está dentro del ActionPerformed de cada Botón?